# How to compute local minima precisely with scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

Say, we want to compute the local minimum of function

```
f = lambda x: x*x
```

using python's scipy:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(f,-10,method='powell',options={'xtol':1e-50})
```

I get

```
 status: 0
 success: True
   direc: array([[ 1.]])
    nfev: 20
     fun: array(1.135959703518257e-28)
       x: array(1.0658141036401503e-14)
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 2
```

The local minimum point `1.0658141036401503e-14` is not good enough. My question is:

Since I already put xtol be 1e-50, which, IMHO, means the threshold of the relative error, why my result is still of the order `1e-14`?

Comment: If you change the `method` to `SLSQP`, you get an exact result (0).  Does that help?

Comment: @John. Thanks. I use f(x)=x*x as a very simple example. I guess SLSQP is for twice continuously differentiable functions only?

Comment: Fair enough.  I suspect you are running into the limits of 64-bit float precision here, but I don't know exactly where in the implementation this is happening.

Comment: See [the method-specific options documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.show_options.html#scipy.optimize.show_options).  The `Powell` method allows for both an `ftol` and and an `xtol`.  Try lowering both to 10^-50.  If that doesn't work I agree with John Zwinck's comment.  Also what is your machine epsilon?

Comment: @Curt F. If I put ftol,  with 'op.minimize(f,-10,method='powell',options={'xtol':1e-50,'ftol':1e-50})', the results are exactly the same as the one with xtol only.  My macheps is 2.22e-16.

Comment: I think you might not be using the correct tool for the job. When you talk about "precise" evaluation, especially when you are supplying mathematical functions (of any kind), you might be better off using symbolic packages, such as sympy. I'd add it as an answer, but am thinking it will get downvoted because you asked *explicitly* for scipy.

Comment: Yes, the main problem is thinking an exact answer can get gotten by numeric methods. They all have their foibles.  For example, using SLSQP gives x = 0.0 when the starting guess is 1.0, but when the guess is reduced to 1E-10 it just returns that. One can always "polish" roots, but you need to understand the limits of the methods, both in general and for each specific algorithm if you really want to dive deep into their performance.  Curling up with Knuth or even the Numerical Recipes book provides insight.

Comment: If the `x` in your equation were measured in light years, an error of 1E-14 would be equivalent to the approximate length of a football field.

Answer (score 0):

As *John Zwinck*, *zell* and *Jon Custer* pointed out: You're running out of digits. To demonstrate it, let's substitute `x = zz[0] + zz[1]*1e-8`, hence `f(x) = x*x = zz[0]*zz[0] + 2*zz[0]*zz[1]*1e-8 + zz[1]*1e-16`, which results in the following code:

```
import scipy.optimize as sopt
import numpy as np

f = lambda zz: zz[0]*zz[0] + 2*zz[0]*zz[1]*1e-8 + zz[1]*zz[1]*1e-16

zz0 = np.array([-10, 0])
rr = sopt.minimize(f, zz0, method='powell')
print("argmin(x**2) = {}".format(rr.x[0] + rr.x[1]*1e-8))
# Output: argmin(x**2) = -1.22858775101e-25
```

Normally, one would expect that a two-dimensional problem has a worse convergence that a well-behaving one-dimensional one. Here, the second dimension increases the number of effective digits. I chose `1e-8` to be the square root of the machine epsilon of `2.2e-16`. Varying that factor, shows that this implementation of the Powell algorithm obviously has trouble with small floating point numbers.

As already written in the comments: The smarter approach is to use better suited solvers. Check out [mpm math's root finding](http://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/mpmath/calculus/optimization.html#root-finding-and-optimization), if you need a high number of digits.